# Django is terribly slow on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, osx-lion

I recently did a clean install of OS X Lion. I'm now running Django 1.2.5 on Python 2.6.6 using virtualenv. The MySQL version is 5.5.14 (installed via homebrew). When I run the test suite of one of my applications now, it is just **insanely** slow. Usually the whole test suite would take about 4-5 minutes. Now after that time it isn't even done with ~30%.

Anybody any ideas on how I could narrow down the bottleneck? Could it be the fresh install of MySQL is just configured bad? How would I benchmark MySQL best and what might be the issue with the (InnoDB) tables? Maybe I'm not the only one having these problems...

Comment: check activity monitor anything unusual going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so to answer my own question, I found out it was actually just bad default settings for the MySQL installation. I ran over this script called [MySQLTuner](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl) and it showed me some variables I should change. After following it's recommendations the tests finish in normal times again.

Comment: Do you run MySQL in a ramdisk? I do, and I made the recommended changes, but still have a super slow test suite. Thanks for the tip on MySQLTuner though! (It did help a little)

Answer (score 2):

According to this TechCrunch article: [Nine Things You Should Do After Installing OS X Lion](http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/21/os-x-lion-new-features/), Lion is re-indexing your files. Leave it alone for a good few hours.

Comment: It's already been 2 days the machine has been running without interruption. All the rest is OK performance-wise. It's really just the django application where I feel the issues. Don't have any other app using MySQL atm though, to compare the MySQL performance...

Answer (score 0):

Following link may help >> http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/speeding-up-django-unit-test-runs-with-mysql

I config /etc/my.cnf with this suggestion, and Django runs fast!

```
[mysqld]
skip-sync-frm=OFF
```